# Error while installing Plotly js with angular 12

Tags: angular, plotly, plotly.js, angular12

I am trying to install plotly js in angular 12 app by following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js?activeTab=readme) article.  But I'm getting compilations error in typescript,

Please help me to solve this error.

[AppMoudle.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuKzw.png)

After clearing the above compilation issue by following this [article](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md), I'm getting below build error

[Build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HZhz.png)

Comment: Did you install both, angular-plotly.js and plotly.js? The command says `npm install angular-plotly.js plotly.js`.

Comment: @FelixLemke Yes,      "angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.0",
"plotly.js": "^2.3.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm install angular-plotly.js plotly.js-dist-min --save
npm install @types/plotly.js-dist-min --save-dev
```

In the AppModule, do the follow:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
import { PlotlyViaCDNModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
    
PlotlyViaCDNModule.setPlotlyVersion('latest');
    
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        PlotlyViaCDNModule,
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use the latest version of Plotly.js, but you can use a minor version as well.

You can take a look my project in Angular 12 with Plotly:

https://github.com/cristofima/AngularPlotly